# Why people only visit or care Kashi after 60 years?

Tags: belief, temple

When we ask people what is the history of Kashi temple, why is it in such bad condition so long? People suppress by saying why do you think of it in early age. Kashi is the topic after 60.

So after 60, people does nothing except wait for Death. So, is this could be the reason for its under development?

Why youngsters don't visit that and witness the conditions before 60?

Is this a systematic way of suppressing Hinduism?

Comment: You do have a very false notion. I am currently 20+ years old & visited Kashi the previous year, alongside Prayaga. Kashi's underdevelopment is due to ignorance of the masses regarding Kashi's intricacies. At Kashi I saw a luxury yacht playing decadant Bollywood music on loudspeakers & featuring light-&-sound dance party on its deck cruising the Ganga at Dasashwamedha Ghat. Before visiting Kashi, I had consulted a website that listed all the shrines mentioned in Kashikhanda, but I saw that the temples of Kuvereshwara & Shukreshwara (mentioned in that website) were broken down for the Corridor.

Comment: Similarly the shrine of Avimukteshwara (mentioned in Kashikhanda) was torn down to make way for the extension of the shrine of Tarakeshwara (consecrated by Ahilyabai Holkar). Some shrines in Kashi don't even have permanent priests attached to them. Kashikhand a mentions the shrine of Bhavani to be situated by the banks of Bhavanikunda but the current shrine of Bhavani is situated within the precints of Annapurna, with no sign of the Bhavanikunda. All this clearly shows that the pilgrims & administration themselves are greatly ignorant about Kashi as described in Kashikhanda.

Comment: Before any name-calling begins[This](https://varanasitemples.in/category/devi-temples/charma-munda-devi/) is the website which lists the existence of separate shrines of Avimukteshwara, Kuvereshwara & Shukreshwara.

Comment: The Yogavasistha says - One should be devoted to dharma from one's youth because the life is imparmanent & nobody knows who will die at what time. The concept that one should devote old age for religious activities is absolutely nonsensical. They reason that indulgence in dharma at a young age will divert away one's attention from material needs. However from my experience, I can say that if the seed of faith aren't sowed early, then it will never sprout perfectly due to the strongly supplanted influence of avidya.